# Проверка значения на уникальность

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Пишу CustomValidator. Написал функцию, которая должна проверять, что значение в заданном TextBox не должно совпадать с другими TextBox. 
Она работает некорректно. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
function IsUnique1(source, args) {
  if (args.Value == "") {
    args.IsValid = false;
  } else {
    if (
      !args.Value.Equals(OrangeBox.Text) && 
      !args.Value.Equals(RedBox.Text) && 
      !args.Value.Equals(WhiteBox.Text) && 
      !args.Value.Equals(GreenBox.Text) 
    ) {
      args.IsValid = true;
    } else {
      args.IsValid = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Сколько у Вас TextBox'ов на странице? Не проверяете ли Вы значение со своим же TextBox?

Comment: Действительно ли это javascript? `String.prototype.Equals` сами реализовывали?

Comment: @vp_arth, Ну формально `args.Value` не обязан быть строкой, он обязан сравниваться со строкой :-)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал валидатор так: задал бы объект со значениями полей `arrBox = [...]`. А потом бы передавал этот массив и значение которое надо провалидировать.

```js
var arrBox = [
 {id:'OrangeBox', value: 1},
 {id:'RedBox', value: 2},
 {id:'WhiteBox', value: 3},
  {id:'GreenBox', value: 4}
];

var value = 5;


function isUnique(arr, val) {
   return !arr.find(function (item) {
        return item.value == val;
   });
}

var r = isUnique(arrBox, value);
console.log(r)
```

А у вас получается избыточный код, который попробуй ещё поддержи. Потом добавиться, какой то BlackBox, потому будет аналогичная форма, но не будет RedBox, например, и надо буде писать новую функцию IsUnique2.